# Recursive ExpressionBody

Tags: c#, reflection

I have property with ChildAttributte

```
public class AircraftFlight : BaseEntity
{
    [Child(FilterType.Equal, "ParentTypeId", 13)]
    public ICollection<ItemFileLink> Files { get; set; }
}
```

I create expression

```
Expression<Func<AircraftFlight, IEnumerable<ItemFileLink>>> q = 
    i => i.Files.Where(f => f.ParentTypeId == 13);
```

My task create this expression using reflection using method with this params. Go to T type and Find property(Files). Then on property Files call method `Where` with `condition(ParentTypeId == inputText)`

```
private Expression<Func<T, IEnumerable<TChild>>> ExpressionConstructor<T, TChild>(
    string prop (property Files),
    string propertyName (property ParentTypeId), 
    object inputText, 
    FilterType condition)
```

Can you help guys?

Comment: Yes, this is absolutely viable (although I don't see in what way it's *recursive* as per your title). It sounds to me like you need to use reflection to: a) get the property; b) get the attribute from the property; c) get the collection element type of the property; d) get the property specified in the attribute from that element type; e) build the expression with all the bits. Could you give details about what you've tried out of that, and where you're having difficulties?

Comment: Difficulties in call where Method with condition

Comment: So please provide a [mcve] of how far you've got. Have you already fetched the first property, the attribute, and the second property based on that attribute?

Comment: Yes, I alredy have all params

Comment: Right, so please show that - or ignore the attribute part, and just show how far you've got in terms of the `Where` call, passing in all the aspects you've already managed to obtain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can do it purely through Expression API. I have added my assumptions for how your classes look like. If there are deviations, you will need to change the expression set up.

Before getting into code, this appears to be fairly static code which does not appear to need reflection. I suppose you have a valid reason for going this route. Exactly same thing can be implemented through classes under reflection namespace as well.

```
class AircraftFlight
{
    internal ICollection<ItemFileLink> Files { get; set; }
}

class ItemFileLink
{
    internal int ParentTypeId { get; set; }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Type aircraftFlightType = typeof(AircraftFlight); 
    Type itemFileLinkType = typeof(ItemFileLink);
    // Create object of desired type
    ParameterExpression aircraftFlightObject = Expression.Parameter(aircraftFlightType, "parameter");

    // Locate files property
    MemberExpression filesPropertyExpression = Expression.Property(aircraftFlightObject, "Files");

    // Getting where method call for Files property
    var whereMethod = new Func<IEnumerable<ItemFileLink>, Func<ItemFileLink, bool>, IEnumerable<ItemFileLink>>(Enumerable.Where);

    // Getting item types and parentId property
    ParameterExpression itemFileLinkExpression = Expression.Parameter(itemFileLinkType);
    Expression parentTypeIdExpression = Expression.Property(itemFileLinkExpression, "ParentTypeId");

    // Create the lambda for where method (your condition for where clause)
    var lambdaForWhere = Expression.Lambda(Expression.Equal(parentTypeIdExpression, Expression.Constant(13)), itemFileLinkExpression);

    // Create where method call
    var whereMethodGeneric = whereMethod.Method.GetGenericMethodDefinition().MakeGenericMethod(itemFileLinkType);
    MethodCallExpression whereCall = Expression.Call(null, whereMethodGeneric, filesPropertyExpression, lambdaForWhere);

    // Create parent object
    AircraftFlight aircraftFlight = new AircraftFlight();
    aircraftFlight.Files = new Collection<ItemFileLink>();
    aircraftFlight.Files.Add(new ItemFileLink { ParentTypeId = 1 });
    aircraftFlight.Files.Add(new ItemFileLink { ParentTypeId = 13 });
    aircraftFlight.Files.Add(new ItemFileLink { ParentTypeId = 1 });
    aircraftFlight.Files.Add(new ItemFileLink { ParentTypeId = 13 });
    aircraftFlight.Files.Add(new ItemFileLink { ParentTypeId = 1 });
    aircraftFlight.Files.Add(new ItemFileLink { ParentTypeId = 1 });

    // Invoke
    var result = Expression.Lambda(whereCall, aircraftFlightObject).Compile().DynamicInvoke(aircraftFlight);
}
```

Update:
If you do not know the type of Files property, you can first create a prototype where method and then make a specific generic method. Following code might help:

```
    // Prepare prototype where method
    var whereMethod = new Func<IEnumerable<object>, Func<object, bool>, IEnumerable<object>>(Enumerable.Where);

    // Prepare specific where method. itemFileLinkType can be replaced by any other type
    var whereMethodGeneric = whereMethod.Method.GetGenericMethodDefinition().MakeGenericMethod(itemFileLinkType);
```

Comment: Thank you!!! But one question you create  var whereMethod = new Func<IEnumerable<ItemFileLink>, Func<ItemFileLink, bool>, IEnumerable<ItemFileLink>>(Enumerable.Where); , but if i dont know type may i pass Type(ItemFileLink or Another) like param?

Comment: @EvgeniiBabak Updated the response

Comment: I dont understand what you are trying to do. Generics expect a type. Nothing else between those <>